# Working JS code gets error message when compressed : "Syntax error: Name Expected"

Tags: javascript

I am creating a class that enables me to select any element by selector and quickly apply JS methods on it. I have a small issue with the code bellow (which is the first part of my code). When I compress it with Koala or on jscompress.com I get an error message:

> SyntaxError: Name expected (line: 31, col: 31)

The line corresponds to the wrapper method starting with `$.prototype.method`. I don't understand what's wrong since my code is perfectly working both in local and in live website.

Somehow there's an error there. I tried changing the variable `name` to another one but it gave me the same error.

```
var $ = function(element) {
  if(!(this instanceof $)) {
    return new $(element);
  }

  // select all elements with this identifier
  this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(element);
  this.length = this.elements.length;
  if(this.length == 0) {
    return this;
  }

  // by default select the first element of querySelectorAll
  this.element = this.elements[0];
  this.css = this.element.style;

  // first method applied will be exectuted directly
  this.delayTime = 0;
}

// add a time to the delay timer
$.prototype.delay = function(delayTime) {
  // set a delay for the following method applied
  this.delayTime += delayTime;

  return this;
}

// wraps the method into a setTimeout
$.prototype.method = function(name, fn) {
  $.prototype[name] = function(...args) {
    var that = this;
    if(this.length != 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        // only one relevant param is passed
        fn(that, args[0]);
      }, this.delayTime);
      return this;
    }
    return 'element does not exist!';
  };
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `...` is an EMCA2016 feature, you need to use a minifier that has support for it.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pointing to this line:

```
  $.prototype[name] = function(...args) {
```

because the minifier you're using doesn't understand ECMAScript 6 spread syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is referring to the spread operator – `...args`.

The spread operator is relatively new and probably isn't supported by your minifier.

To fix the error, remove `...args` from the arguments list on line 31. On line 36, use the `arguments` object instead – `fn(that, arguments[0]);`

Comment: I just realised, it didn't actually worked correctly because the `arguments` array wasn't defined inside `setTimeout()`. I had to define another variable before the setTimeout like so:  `var args = arguments`. Then execute fn with args as a parameter: `fn(that, args[0]`